# Altering body text of a node before the page is rendered

Tags: theming

I am using the Zen theme. I want to alter the body text before it is rendered as a page. In particular, I want to replace a string with another string. I thought that the general solution for this would be to place the code in the the theme_preprocess_node hook in my sub-theme's template.php. Here is the code that I've got so far:

```
<?php
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if ((isset($variables['body'][0]['value'])) && (preg_match('/suppose/i', $variables['body'][0]['value']))) {
        dpm('string was found in "value"');
        $variables['body'][0]['value'] = preg_replace('/suppose/i', 'new tring', $variables['body'][0]['value']);
    }
    if ((isset($variables['body'][0]['safe_value'])) && (preg_match('/suppose/i', $variables['body'][0]['safe_value']))) {
        dpm('string was found in "safe_value"');
        $variables['body'][0]['safe_value'] = preg_replace('/suppose/i', 'new tring', $variables['body'][0]['safe_value']);
    }        
}
?>
```

However, this has no effect what so ever. I do get a positive match - this I can verify by the debug dpm() display.

Am I simply trying to rewrite the wrong sub-array?

Thanks in advance,
Valera Rozuvan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not a good solution but it works fine.

In node.tpl.php

```
<?php print hide($content['body']); ?>
<?php print render($content); ?>
<?php print $newbody; ?>
```

In template.php

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 if ((isset($variables['body'][0]['value'])) && (preg_match('/suppose/i', $variables['body'][0]['value']))) {
   $variables['newbody'] = str_replace('suppose', 'new string', $variables['body'][0]['value']);
 }
}
```

As I've said this is a patch solution and I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in mytheme_preprocess_node:

`function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) { 

  // Collect / create / adjust new body content
  $new_body = 'xyz';

  // Assign to output
  $vars['content']['body'][0]['#markup'] = $new_body
}`

After looking through the vars array a bit, I'm a little surprised at the amount of redundant data there.  There are a few different places where the body text is recorded, usually as an array.

Note that the node body will likely have a 'safe value' and a 'value'.  You'll probably want to use safe almost all the time, but it might be good to check on the filter type selected in $vars['body'][0]['format'] to select which of the body values you'll want to output and display.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $contenue = $variables['body'][0]['value'];
  $variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'] = $contenue;
}
```